# Oracle - Count condition case

Tags: sql, oracle, function, count, conditional-statements

I am facing a problem with a query. My goal is to get all product names, unit of mass, quantity and number of pallets they are located in. The problem is with number of pallets of item.

QUERY:

```
SELECT "Product_Name"
       , "Unit_of_Mass"
       , SUM("Quantity_Per_UOM")
       , Count(*) as "Number_Of_Pallet" 
FROM
    (select p.prod_desc as "Product_Name"
           , s.quantity as "Quantity_Per_UOM"
            , u.description as "Unit_of_Mass"
            , s.container_id
            , s.product_id
    from wms_stock s
    join wms_product p on p.product_id = s.product_id
    join wms_uom u on p.uom_base_id = u.uom_id
    )
group by "Product_Name", "Unit_of_Mass"
```

It almost works. The problem is I need to do some condition in Count(*) (that's what I think should be done). In table `wms_stock` I got `product_id` and `container_id`, and when in some row they are same it should count the number of pallets as `1` but still add the quantities.

So from first select:

```
 Product_Name | Quantity | UnitOfMass | ContainerId | ProductId
 A            |        2 | kg         |          10 |        11
 A            |        1 | kg         |          10 |        11
 B            |        2 | kg         |          11 |        12
```

I should get result

```
Product_Name | Quantity_Per_UOM | UnitOfMass | Number_Of_Pallet
A            |                3 | kg         |                1
B            |                2 | kg         |                1
```

Comment: You can try `COUNT(DISTINCT Number_Of_Pallet).`

Comment: Doing that made the results in Number_Of_Pallet as 1. Maybe it's not the problem with count and condition.

Comment: Try this -  `COUNT(DISTINCT ContainerId || ProductId)`

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. Could you explain please why do we use OR operator here? Its because Distinct may have only 1 parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below condition in your select list -

```
COUNT(DISTINCT ContainerId || ProductId)
```

Just for your information, `||` is not an operator rather it is concatenation operator in Oracle. So i have just concat both the columns and picked up the distinct from them.

Comment: you should add a separation character between ContainerId and ProductId, e.g. `ContainerId||'#'||ProductId`. Otherwise ContainerId=1 ProductId=11 is in the same group as ContainerId=11 ProductId=1.

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss, thanks for letting me know this small trick. I will remember the same in future.